# Finding Circle-Line collision (as points, not bools) C#

Tags: c#, math, geometry

So unlike everyone here, I'm trying to find the intersections from circle-line collision.

The points are taken from the user input.

```
float cx; //circle center x
float cy; //circle center y
float px; //point x
float py; //point y
float vx; //vector x
float vy; //vector y

float vySq = vy * vy;
float vxSq = vx * vx;
float cxSq = cx * cx;
float rSq = r * r;

float thatPart = ( ( (vy * px) / vx) + py - cy); //so I don't have to re-type it 3 different times

float a = 1 + (vySq/vxSq);

float b = (2 * cx) + ( (2 * vy) * thatPart / vx);

float c = cxSq + ( thatPart * thatPart ) - rSq;

float x1 = QUADRATIC(a, b, c, true);
float x2 = QUADRATIC(a, b, c, false);

float y1 = ((vy * x1) - (vy * px) + (vx * py)) / vx;
float y2 = ((vy * x2) - (vy * px) + (vx * py)) / vx;
```

My QUADRATIC function 100% works, so I am not worried about that.

It's a, b, and c. I receive the wrong values for them. And all this math is based on a pdf given in math class. ([here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rpx66rrluu8vzn/circlelineintersection.pdf?dl=0))

So... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: _(( / h)_ a typo, I assume..

Comment: Why not use reliable names for all parameters? Nobody wants to decrypt that `ee=centerY` and so on.

Comment: @MBo fixed that. Thanks for the tip. And yes, the (( /h) was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The equations in both the PDF and the source code seem unnecessarily complicated, so I will re-establish them in a clenear way (or at least one that pleases me).

The vector from the center of the circle to any point `S` on the line can be written as

```
CS = CP + t V
```

where `t` is an arbitrary parameter.

`S` belongs to the circle when

```
CS² = R² = (CP + t V)²
```

giving the quadratic equation in `t`:

```
V² t² + 2 CP.V t + CP² - R² = 0
```

When you have the values of `t`, plug in the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

### Math Treatment

You have a line with coordinates `(x,y) = (px + vx*t, py + vy*t)` where **t** is an arbitrary parameter.

The line intersects the circle when its coordinates solve `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`.

This leads to the following quadratic equation, to be solved for **t**.

```
t^2 + 2*t*b + a = 0

a = (px^2+py^2-r^2)/(vx^2+vy^2)
b = (px*vx+py*vy)/(vx^2+vy^2)
```

The two solutions are:

```
t = -b ± sqrt(b^2-a)
```

Use the two **t** values into `(x,y)` to get the coordinates.

### Sample Code

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ray = new Ray() {
            Point = new Vector2(-3, 1),
            Direction = new Vector2(2, 0.5f)
        };

        var circle = new Circle
        {
            Center = new Vector2(1, 1),
            Radius = 4
        };

        var points = Geometry.Intersect(circle, ray);
        if(points.Length>0)
        {
            foreach(var point in points)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(point.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circle and Ray do not intersect");
        }
    }
}
```

### Object Oriented Models

```
public class Circle
{
    public Vector2 Center { get; set; }
    public float Radius { get; set; }
}

public class Ray
{
    public Vector2 Point { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Direction { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Along(float t)
    {
        return Point + t*Direction;
    }
}

public static class Geometry
{
    public static Vector2[] Intersect(Circle circle, Ray ray)
    {
        float a = (ray.Point.LengthSquared()-circle.Radius*circle.Radius)/ray.Direction.LengthSquared();
        float b = Vector2.Dot(ray.Point, ray.Direction)/ray.Direction.LengthSquared();

        if(b*b-a>0)
        {
            // two intersection points
            float t1 = -b-(float)Math.Sqrt(b*b-a);
            float t2 = -b+(float)Math.Sqrt(b*b-a);

            return new Vector2[] {
                ray.Along(t1),
                ray.Along(t2),
            };
        }
        else if(b*b-a==0)
        {
            // one intersection point
            float t = -b;
            return new Vector2[] { ray.Along(t) };
        }
        else
        {
            // no intersection, return empty array
            return new Vector2[0];
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>NOTE: Code uses `System.Numerics` library</sub>